# enumerate item showing errors in tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, lua

The below LaTeX **enumerate list** and after **end{equation}\\** showing errors in `tex4ht`. How do solve this? I know to solve this errors through Lua Script. But i would like to know how to fix this type of errors in .cfg file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb,amscd}
\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{author}
\maketitle


In this article we denote 
\begin{equation}
\nu:=\frac{1}{\gamma-1}. \label{Nu}
\end{equation}\\

Let us fix a stratified equilibrium $\rho=\bar{\rho}, P=\bar{P}, S=\bar{S}$, which are functions of $x^3$ only such that .

\begin{enumerate}[10]
\item One should not attempt to prove statements so obvious that nothing more obvious exists with which to prove them.
\item One should prove all theorems which are not quite clear and in the proofs one should use only very obvious axioms or theorems which are accepted or proved.
\end{enumerate}

Let us fix a stratified equilibrium $\rho=\bar{\rho}, P=\bar{P}, S=\bar{S}$, which are functions of $x^3$ only such that .

\end{document}
```

My Lua Script is:

```
for line in io.lines() do
  line = line:gsub("\\end{equation}\\\\", "\\end{equation}")
  line = line:gsub("%^\\mathrm{(.-)}", "^{\\mathrm %1}")
  print(line)
end
```

Comment: never use `\\ ` after equation (in latex or in texht)

Comment: I think you should use your Lua script to clean input files, it is easier than trying to make complex workarounds at the TeX level.

Comment: @michal: Thanks for your reply. If this is not possible in .cfg file finally we will go for Lua Script concept only...

Comment: you get error for this file even for pdflatex, so it would be really hard to fix it in TeX macros without fixing the source. It is just easier to fix the sources using regexes.

Comment: @michal: Thanks. Author is given wrong coding in LaTeX. Now only i saw this pdflatex compiling problem. Thanks for your help. Now my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the necessity of escaping backslashes in Lua strings, you can use `[[...]]` syntax.

```lua
line = line:gsub([[\end{equation}\\]], [[\end{equation}]])
line = line:gsub([[%^\mathrm{(.-)}]], [[^{\mathrm %1}]])
```

Comment: @David Carlisle: I have received this file from author. But how to do in the .cfg file. Kindly advise.

Comment: @David Carlisle: And also when running `filter.lua` each LaTeX command before and after extra enter mark(\n) is present. How to avoid this also. Example : \begin{equation}

\nu:=\frac{1}{\gamma-1}. \label{Nu}

\end{equation}

Comment: even so it's better just to fix errors in the document in an editor rather than try to fix them on the fly. Sorry I haven't written any te4ht for many years can't help there, but I  wouldn't fix it at that level.

Comment: @David: Thanks for your reply. I hope michal will solve this problem and waiting for the same...

Comment: why is it a problem? the system should not have to deal with erroneous input files. Just delete the erroneous `\\ ` If there was an undefined command or other error in the input would you expect tex4ht to handle that as well?

Comment: @David: I have solved \\ problem using `make4ht` with config. Actually if any errors we will do automatically try to solve the problem through scripts. I got idea in Lua. But i want to fix in .cfg file. Now `\begin{enumerate}[10]` need to rename `\begin{enumerate}` only. Trying still now...